# How to adjust height of bootstrap-vue table and make it scrollable with fixed header

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a div with b-table inside it.
I want to adjust the height of the table and make it scrollable with fixed header.
Please someone help.
here is my code.

here is the code inside template:

```html
<div class="tbl-barangay">
    <b-table striped hover :items="items" :fields="fields">
        <template v-slot:cell(name)="data">
            <router-link to="/destination">{{ data.value }}</router-link>
        </template>

        <template v-slot:cell(completeaddress)="data">
            {{ data.item.address.street }}, {{ data.item.address.city }}
        </template>
    </b-table>
</div>
```

here is my scoped style:

```css
.tbl-barangay {
    height: 150px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So, to make it scrollable  - add this pass the responsive prop to the `b-table` tag. e.g:
For a horizontal scroll:

```
<b-table responsive :items="items"></b-table>
```

Where `responsive` is just an option for the type of scroll-able.

For vertical scroll, use `sticky-headers`, eg:

```
<b-table sticky-header :items="items" head-variant="light"></b-table>
```

Assuming you have some data defined in `items`.

For fixed header: simply pass the `fixed` element to the `<b-table>` tag, e.g:

```
 <b-table fixed responsive :items="items" :fields="fields" ... >
```

And for the height: in your css - set the `sticky-header` prop to a valid css height with units.  eg:

```
sticky-header="200px"
```

For more :visit this [doc](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/)

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of BootstrapVue (current version is 2.0.1)

Comment: Note `fixed` is not for "fixing" the headers to the top, it is for generating a `fixed layout` of the table (where it makes all columns the same width)